# Convert struct array to cell of structs and vice versa

Tags: matlab, octave, cell-array, matlab-struct

I often have to work with struct arrays and cells containing scalar structs with identical fieldnames which I call an "unpacked struct array" and I wonder if there aren't already functions in Matlab and/or GNU Octave which helps converting between those two representations.

A struct array:

```
foo(1).a = 3;
foo(1).b = pi;
foo(2).a = 5;
foo(2).b = 2.718;
```

Apparently `num2cell` works in one way in GNU Octave ([although it isn't mentioned in the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Creating-Cell-Arrays.html#XREFnum2cell)):

```
ret = num2cell (foo)
ret =
{
  [1,1] =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      a =  3
      b =  3.1416

  [1,2] =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      a =  5
      b =  2.7180

}
```

But I'm looking for the reverse part, converting `ret` back to `foo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
foo2 = [ret{:}]; % or equivalently foo2 = horzcat(ret{:});
```

That is, just concatenate the cell array's contents horizontally.

Check:

```
>> foo(1).a = 3;
foo(1).b = pi;
foo(2).a = 5;
foo(2).b = 2.718;
>> ret = num2cell (foo);
>> foo2 = [ret{:}];
>> isequal(foo, foo2)
ans =
  logical
   1
```

Comment: Omg, I now remember that I've done this before a year ago while working with image regionprops centroids.... I completly forgot that it's possible to concatenate scalar structs if the fields are identical.

Comment: _I now remember that I've done this before a year ago_: happens to me a lot :-)